# Select ALL matching rows from a target table if they match ALL rows from a source table

Tags: sql-server

I need to retrieve data from the target (table 2) which has ALL matching values from the source table (table 1), by the same CategoryID.

If **all** of the resources in the source table don't have a corresponding resource in the target table (per CategoryID), then no data should be returned.

I tried a `NOT EXISTS` SQL clause but it's not working for me ....

I tried the following query

```
SELECT b.CategoryID,b.[Name]
FROM table2 b
INNER JOIN #table1 a 
  ON a.ResourceName=b.[Name]
WHERE  
 0 < (
        SELECT count(1)
        FROM #table1 temp 
        WHERE
        temp.ResourceName NOT IN (b.[Name])           
      );
```

**My Data :**

[image]

**Expected result :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem, I did the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9MBlYQ0f)):

```
CREATE TABLE master
(
  dat VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO master VALUES
('resource_1'),
('resource_2'),
('resource_NA');
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE resource
(
  id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  category_id INT NOT NULL,
  name        VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT r_fk FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES master (dat),
  CONSTRAINT r_c_id_name_uq UNIQUE (category_id, name)
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO resource VALUES -- just a small sample, 2 category_ids have all 3 dats from master
(1,  '1001', 'resource_1'),
(2,  '1001', 'resource_2'),
(3,  '1002', 'resource_1'),
(4,  '1002', 'resource_2'),
(5,  '1002', 'resource_NA'),
(6,  '1003', 'resource_1'),
(7,  '1003', 'resource_2'),
(8,  '1004', 'resource_NA'), 
(9,  '1005', 'resource_1'),
(10, '1005', 'resource_2'),
(11, '1005', 'resource_NA');
```

Then, we use COUNT() AS a [window function](https://learnsql.com/blog/count-over-partition-by/):

```
SELECT 
  r.*, 
  COUNT(r.category_id) OVER (PARTITION BY category_id 
                             ORDER BY category_id) AS cnt
FROM resource r;
```

Result:

```
id  category_id name        cnt
1   1001        resource_1    2
2   1001        resource_2    2
3   1002        resource_1    3
4   1002        resource_2    3
5   1002        resource_NA   3
6   1003        resource_1    2
7   1003        resource_2    2
8   1004        resource_NA   1
9   1005        resource_1    3
10  1005        resource_2    3
11  1005        resource_NA   3
```

And then we join this result (as a CTE) to `master`:

```
WITH tab AS
(
  SELECT 
    r.id, r.category_id AS c_id, r.name, 
    COUNT(r.category_id) OVER (PARTITION BY category_id 
                             ORDER BY category_id) AS cnt
  FROM resource r
)
SELECT 
  r.id, r.category_id AS rc_id, r.name,
  -- t.id, t.c_id, t.name, t.cnt -- uncomment to see what's going on
FROM
  tab t
JOIN resource r
  ON r.name = t.name
  AND t.cnt = (SELECT COUNT(dat) FROM master)
  AND t.c_id = r.category_id
ORDER BY r.id;
```

Result:

```
id  rc_id  name
 3  1002   resource_1
 4  1002   resource_2
 5  1002   resource_NA
 9  1005   resource_1
10  1005   resource_2
11  1005   resource_NA
```

which is correct for the sample data I have used.

In future, when asking questions, please do **not** post images of code, SQL or any text for the reasons outlined in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530).

Also, in future, when you have a question like this, please go to the fiddle [site](https://dbfiddle.uk) and make one for the question. This helps reduce errors through typos or whatever - only a [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) for the data (your own source) and it elminates duplication of effort by those trying to help you!

[Window functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/) are extremely powerful and will pay back any effort you put into learning them many times over - I suggest you start with the two links I have posted and work from there until you have mastered them!

p.s. welcome to dba.se!